# Gridview problem with the rows autosizing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rows, autosize

Basically my rows autosize depending on the number of items it has. If it has one item then,,the header, pager, are all in a big size.

How could I make the header and footer fixed,, and may be insert a few empty rows not to extend the item..

I tried to do so with the page change event..but not very successfully so i need help..

This is what i thought of so far:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.GridView1.Rows.Count < this.GridView1.PageSize)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow tt in GridView1.Rows)
        { tt.Height = Unit.Pixel(30); }

    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.GridView1.Rows.Count < this.GridView1.PageSize)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow tt in GridView1.Rows)
        { tt.Height = Unit.Pixel(30); }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you saying that you want the header & footer rows to not change their height but you want all of the other rows to be 30 pixels high?

Answer (score 1):

Give `CSS` for your Gridview, and mainly for your (ie CSS)  Gridviews `Headerstyle and Rowstyle` Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with stylesheet. Let say if only one record apply one CSS Style other vise normal style. I think that is possible. 
Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: Thats not the answer ...I had to remove the height attribute from the gridview